# c# XML Serialization How to serialize flat list with xsi:nil="true"

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xmlserializer

When serializing a flat List (i.e. with XmlElement-Attribute) and IsNullable=true, the output doesn't have the xsi:nil="true" entry if the List is null.

```
 [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement(IsNullable = true)]
public List<OrdinanceValueType> ordinance
{
    get
    {
        return this.ordinanceField;
    }
    set
    {
        this.ordinanceField = value;
    }
}
```

With XmlArray-Attribute, it works, but the list isn't flat anymore.

Is there a way to get xsi:nil="true" with a flat list?